# Vertically aligning floated DIVs with varying heights?

Tags: jquery, html, css, cross-browser, css-float

**See my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Awg3u/) to see what currently happens**

I have some divs with content of varying height. The width is always the same.

Each row should contain two columns, but I would like the start of each div in a row to be at the same height. Contrast this to say the jQuery Masonry plugin, where all the "bricks" are squeezed together to remove spaces.

What's a good, cross-browser way to achieve this? My idea was to clear the float for every 2nd nth child, but I believe IE doesn't support this?

I believe I could also do something with jQuery, but is it tidy? Will I have learnt anything in order to fix it next time the problem occurs?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="a" class="box">        Some content<br />Div A</div>
<div id="b" class="box">        Some content<br />Div B</div>
<div id="c" class="box">        Some content<br />Div C</div>
<div id="d" class="box">        Some content<br />Div D</div>
<div id="e" class="box">        Some content<br />Div E</div>
<div id="f" class="box">        Some content<br />Div F</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper { width: 444px; }
.box {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
    }
#a { height: 200px; }
#b { height: 180px; }
#c { height: 100px; }
#d { height: 80px; }
#e { height: 50px; }
#f { height: 50px; }
```

Comment: *start of each div in a row to be at the same height* I'm not sure what this means. Do you mean you want the topmost div of each column to be the same height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind? It does use jQuery and adds a bit of extra markup - not sure if that's acceptable.

http://jsfiddle.net/Awg3u/7/

I've only tested in Chrome/FF so far, and haven't checked in IE yet.

Comment: Or should the divs in both columns be the same height?

Comment: This seems to work well. I accept that jQuery is probably needed but this is quite a neat function. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sometimes jQuery is just the thing. I'm tantalized by the CSS-only option, though. Glad this worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use display:inline-block

http://jsfiddle.net/Awg3u/1/

Comment: http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

Comment: "...there’s one giant drawback, that **might or might not apply** to your use case." and personally I do not see that as an enormous drawback especially when this method has so much usefulness.

Comment: Please note that `inline-block` is only decent supported by IE>=8

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to find the maximum height for each box and then take the largest and set every other box to that height.

There should be any number of jQuery plugins that can do this or you can roll your own

Comment: I thought of this but I'm not too hot at creating jQuery functions. Essentially I would need to compare each `even` DIV to its `odd` equivalent, decide which is the longest, then apply that height to the shorter one?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what you want correctly.

If not correct me please.

If you want the all the first divs of the rows to have the same height (based on the first div) you could do something like:

```
(function() {
    var first = true;
    var height = 0;
    var pos;
    $('.box').each(function() {
        if (first) { // do we have the first div?
            height = $(this).height(); // set height and pos from left of first div to be used by other divs
            pos = $(this).position();
        }
        first = false;

        var current_pos = $(this).position();
        if (current_pos.left == pos.left) { // are we the first div in a row, e.g. the most left div?
            $(this).height(height); // set height to match the first div
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Awg3u/3/

Comment: Sorry, I mean the columns in each row should start at the same vertical position.

Answer (score 0):

You can add clearing div after every 2 blocks as follows:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div..................>
```

Or you can wrap your rows in a new DIV.

```
<div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
.......etc.
```

Comment: The Divs are created on the fly though, so I would have to add the clearing class with jQuery afterwards though I believe. If I were going to do that, I may as well try and hack together a function for changing the DIV height if I've understood it correctly.

Comment: All blocks must be of the same height? And equal to the height of the tallest div ?