# automatic height for floating divs in a row?

Tags: javascript, css, css-float

I am developing kinda an alltop feed agregator for a client of mine.  I have it as a completely fluid responsive layout and it works great but there is a small tweak I would like to make.

http://www.paulhanak.com/clients/topmb/index.php

I have all the divs floated left. As you resize the browser, you will see it adapt, forcing divs down accordingly....

So I set up all the divs to be a fixed height of 220px.  Well, sometimes that is wayyyy to much space at the bottom.  Sometimes, the titles are long enough to fill it up just fine.  Ultimately, it would be nice to have a script compare row by row and make the appropriate height adjustments by finding the max height of each of the divs and set the others accordingly...

Any other thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following custom jQuery code to work out how the divs are arranged into rows, and then loop through each row and work out the correct maximum height for the contents of each div in the row, and then set the height of all the divs in that row to that value.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var $blocks = $('.block'),
        firstBlockTop = $blocks.first().offset().top,
        lastOffsetTop = firstBlockTop;
    var rows = [],
        currentRow = 0,
        i, rowCount, j, colCount, height;
    $blocks.each(function(index, element) {
        var $div = $(element),
            thisOffsetTop = $div.offset().top;
        if (thisOffsetTop !== lastOffsetTop) {
            currentRow++;
        }
        rows[currentRow] = (rows[currentRow] || []);
        rows[currentRow].push($div);
        lastOffsetTop = thisOffsetTop;
    });
    console.log(rows);

    function maxHeight(array) {
        var maxHeight = -1,
            innerHeight;
        for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
            // calculate the actual total height for the inner items
            innerHeight = 0;
            array[i].children().each(function() {
                innerHeight += $(this).outerHeight(true);
            });
            maxHeight = Math.max(innerHeight, maxHeight);
        }
        return maxHeight;
    }
    // now loop through each row and set the height of each div to the max height for the row
    for (i = 0, rowCount = rows.length; i < rowCount; i++) {
        height = maxHeight(rows[i]);
        console.log('Row ' + i + ', maxHeight = ' + height);
        for (j = 0, colCount = rows[i].length; j < colCount; j++) {
            rows[i][j].height(height);
        }
    }
});​
```

There may be slight performance improvements you could make to this code, but hopefully it gives you a good baseline.

Comment: Did you just write all that from scratch!? Holy comoly! VERY much thank you.  Some of that is quite a bit above my head but I can totally see what is going on there!!!  I do have a problem though....  I can't get it to work. lol  I implemented it on my site and removed all "height" instances from the css just to be sure... but nothing...  please tell me there is something stupid I missed? :P

Comment: Well, this is odd, I just noticed that it only works in Firefox! Of course, as well it also only works on window resize. The divs are all funky on first page load, but that's easily fixable.  I dunno though, the more I tinker, it seems like it works on the first row only in the other browsers, OR that could just be luck...

Answer (score 0):

I think you define min-height:220px;

Comment: This would not allow all divs to be the same height or align across the page.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the checked answer on the question asked here. [Vertically aligning floated DIVs with varying heights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904855/vertically-aligning-floated-divs-with-varying-heights)

The person uses jquery to add another div that clears the div on both sides of divs to line up them like a table.

```
.clear {clear:both;}
```

the above CSS is what I normally use.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts!  What you sent though is based on a 2 column layout with fixed widths.  I have a TBD column layout without fixed widths.  I am going to bookmark that though! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something that comes right to my mind is to get all the heights of those divisions that you want to compare and obtain their value, then determine which is the tallest or shortest and apply this height to the rest. For example, using jquery, lets suppose they all have the class "div_box"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var tallest = 0;    
$('.div_box').each(function() {
        if(tallest < this.height()){
          tallest = this.height()
        }
    });
})
```

Then you can apply the same height to all of them:

```
 $('.div_box').each(function() {
          this.height() = tallest ;
 });
```

All together would look like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var tallest = 0;    
    $('.div_box').each(function() {
            if(tallest < this.height()){
              tallest = this.height()
            }
        });

      $('.div_box').each(function() {
              this.height() = tallest ;
     });
    })
```

Ultimately, if you want to set them all tho the shortest compare:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var shortest = 10000;  //just give a big value here  
    $('.div_box').each(function() {
            if(shortest > this.height()){
              shortest = this.height()
            }
        });
     $('.div_box').each(function() {
                  this.height() = shortest ;
         });


})
```

Comment: This doesn't set each row to the minimum height for the row, instead it sets all divs to be the same height, which is not what the OP was hoping for.

Comment: So close Eddy! Thank you.  Like Greg said though, if I have one very tall one 3 rows down and the entire first row is short, then ALL of them would be set to long, not just the row that is 3 rows down.  Thanks a bunch! I like the simplicity of the code and adding it to my snippets. :)

Comment: No problem, I am glad I could help, I am still a bit confused about what you are trying to do, but maybe, if I understand properly, if you just don't give any height to your divisions they will all automatically get the shortest height possible individually. Am I close?

Comment: @EddyXP You are correct that they will all be the shortest height possible.  BUT when you float things of different heights, they do not line up correctly.  So in order to float all these "boxes" correctly, each ROW of boxes needs to be the same height.  Thanks again!

Comment: Then maybe set them all to the tallest div found so they will all be aligned :). BTW did you fix the problem? If not I would love to help you, sounds interesting.